# Search with Ruby on Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, search

I am currently learning Ruby on Rails, however, I have run into a slight issue, I am unable to create a text field from which to search.  I so far have a working DB and web page (albeit an ugly one), however, I am having a problem with this simple function, here is my code so far:

```
<h1>Listing articles</h1>

<%= link_to 'New article', new_article_path %> 

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Text</th>
    <th colspan="3"></th>
  </tr>

  <% @articles.each do |article| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= article.title %></td>
      <td><%= article.text %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Show', article_path(article) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_article_path(article) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', article_path(article),
              method: :delete,
              data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>


  <strong>Search Title:</strong>
  text_field_tag(:id)
  <%= @article = Article.find(params[:id]) %>
  <% end %>

</table>
```

error

```
/Users/jake/Documents/internships/rails/search/app/views/articles/index.html.erb:31: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input
```

just for the web page, any help would be strongly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "I am having a problem with this simple function" - what's the problem? Is an error coming up? Can you post it?

Comment: sure, my bad, its not generating a search field or searching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try looking through this code:

In your html:

```
 <% form_tag projects_path, :method => 'get' do %>
     <p>
        <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
        <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
     </p>
 <% end %>
```

In your controller:

```
def index
    @projects = Project.search(params[:search])
end
```

and in the model

```
def self.search(search)
    if search
        find(:all, :conditions => ['name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
    else
        find(:all)
    end
end
```

Here is the [link](http://railscasts.com/episodes/37-simple-search-form)

Also as I'm doing in my project, you can create separate action in your index/welcome controller called search:

```
def search
end
```

Then configure route in your routes.rb like so(not sure exactly this will work)

```
get 'welcome/' => 'welcom#search', as: 'search'
```

And then in view create a form:

```
<%= form_tag search_path, method: 'get', remote: true, id: "garage-search" %>
     <%= text_field_tag :search %>
<% end %>
```

This will send search request by AJAX to your search controller. There you can process it as needed.

Also try look [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eUtUquKc2qQ). Very clearly explained..

Comment: I was trying this before, however, I ended with an issue ` <% form_tag projects_path, :method => 'post' do %>`,  ` NameError in Articles#index`

Comment: well, its not letting me mark those properly as `code`, but it is error code

Comment: Have you tried <%= form_tag ... %> ? With equals sign.

Comment: same error unfortunately ` <%= form_tag projects_path, :method => 'get' do %>`

Comment: Also take a look at the second screencast I've linked. It's pretty good one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106121/discussion-between-arseni-prokharchyk-and-anon).